# Kubernetes deployment where each pod is accessible through public IP

Tags: kubernetes

I have deployment of streaming servers that I need to track and manage accessed to each pod. Let's say that client will receive from manager pod response that streaming pod 1 is ready to be used. What is the best way to have publicly exposed each pods for that particular deployment?

I was thinking about using node ports, but it looks like then I'd need each pod to be on its separate node in order to access them through node public IP.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in support for it. What you can do is to expose each Pod with a separate service, for example using [Metacontroller](https://github.com/metacontroller/metacontroller) with [service-per-pod configuration](https://github.com/metacontroller/metacontroller/tree/master/examples/service-per-pod).

Comment: Thanks, I'm reviewing it. Do you think it's possible to expose several ports on each pod using this setup?

Comment: Yes, I think it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really anything built in for this. You would need a CNI plugin that handle this level of things, doing IPAM from a public block instead of private and integrating with routers within your network. Calico and other BGP-based CNI plugins are capable of this but the setup is some deep (and always system specific) arcana.

Comment: oh well, I'm using AWS EKS, that's going to be intense...